# Proliferation of Fake Accounts

Tags: bug, user-accounts

There is a theme to some of the [new user accounts](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) on MESE. I believe that this is not specific to Math Educators, but is rather a larger problem across StackExchange. Still, I thought it was worth drawing attention to on the off chance that the accounts start to function in some fashion.

For completeness, here is a question:

> What can be done to prevent these users from registering, or maintaining, MESE accounts?

And, for posterity, here is a screenshot of the new users organized by creation date:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. A thing that can be done is delete them. If it does not go away, I think SE will find a solution at some point.

Comment: Related discussion on meta.SE: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746)